# Hibernate, query by property of the composite key

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Following is my entities without nessceary Hibernate annotations for clear.

```
class Main
{
    private SomePk pk;
}

class SomePk
{
    private A a;
    private B b;
}

class A
{
    private String aProperty;
}
class B
{
    private String bProperty;
}
```

I want to do some query like:

```
session.createCtitera(Main.class);
        .add(Restrictrions.eq("pk.a.aProperty", "foo"))
        .list();
```

But this would throw exception "Could not resolve property: pk.a.aPropery of: Main". So how to write the criteria query?

=============updated=======================

===DAO method===

```
public Set<Main> loadMains()
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List list = session.createCriteria(Main.class)
        .createAlias("pk", "p_alias")
        .createAlias("p_alias.a", "a_alias")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("a_alias.aProperty", "j"))
        .list();

    Set<Main> mains = new LinkedHashSet<Main>(list);
    return mains;
}
```

===Class Main===

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN")
public class Main
{
    private SomePK pk;

    private String name;

    @EmbeddedId
    public SomePK getPk()
    {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(SomePK pk)
    {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

===Class SomePK===

```
// ingnore import and package header 

@Embeddable
public class SomePK implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private A a;

    private B b;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A")
    public A getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B")
    public B getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

===Class A===

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A
{
    private String aProperty;

    private long id;

    @Id
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "A_PROPERTY")
    public String getaProperty()
    {
        return aProperty;
    }

    public void setaProperty(String aProperty)
    {
        this.aProperty = aProperty;
    }

}
```

===Class B===

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B
{
    private String bProperty;

    private long id;

    @Id
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "B_PROPERTY")
    public String getbProperty()
    {
        return bProperty;
    }

    public void setbProperty(String bProperty)
    {
        this.bProperty = bProperty;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You edit like bellow answer, and this should work!

Answer (score 3):

Criteria API still does not support nested property directly. You need to create `Alias` to create `Criteria` of nested property. The following code should work for you!

```
 session.createCriteria(Main.class)
 .createAlias("pk.a", "a_alias")
 .add( Restrictions.eqProperty("a_alias.aProperty", "foo")) // .add( Restrictions.eq("a_alias.aProperty", "foo"))
 .list();
```

It is discouraged, not to use `Criteria` for complex situations. When ever possible try to use static queries over dynamically generated one for those situations. That will give you control on your queries for maintaining and optimising them when ever possible.

Cheers and Happy Coding!

Comment: I got this exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: pk . By the way, what does **static queries** mean? I am not good at english. Can you give me an example. Thank you!@SazzadurRahaman

Comment: Do you have the getter setter for the corresponding property? Cause I dont see any other cause of that problem!

Comment: after this line `session.createCtitera(Main.class)` don't put `;`. Just replace your code portion with the above one and try again.

Comment: Please see == updated == in my question. I would like to paste all the related code. But it seems too much letters that I can't post it. So I just add some. Exception stack is only the main park. Other stack is not useful, I think. And, getter and getter are surely provided.

Comment: Can you edit the post showing, domains with their hibernate mapping, please!

Comment: Thanks for your patient. I have updated the question with domains. It's annotation style. Exception stack is omitted for length limit. And, I have tried HQL. HQL can solve several _dotted_ properties. But I'm still expecting the answer for Criteria for interst.

Comment: I ran it. Exception is the same as before: org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: pk